# How would I make my Python Discord bot mimic all messages sent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot using Python (v. 3.6.1). One of its functions detects all messages sent in a channel, processes them, and then responds to the messages in said channel. (At least, that's what I *want* it to do.)

I have tried this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.say(message.content)
```

The function responds when a message is sent, but not in the way that I want it to. I instead get an error:

`discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received NoneType`

How would I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: always use the generic [python] tag for python questions

Comment: Please include the code that is giving you trouble. The error message alone is rather useless. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `bot.say` outside of a command.

> **Can I use bot.say in other places aside from commands?**
>
> No. They only work inside commands due to the way the magic involved works.

http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-bot-say-in-other-places-aside-from-commands

To have the bot repeat every message sent, you can use `send_message`. Below is an example.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, message.content)
```