# Await operator won't work in if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, discord, discord.py

Await won't work in an if statement. Is there any work arounds. I looked for like an hour and nothing found about it.

Source Code:

https://pastebin.com/fCu1Txg9

Thank you for the help if I get any!

Error:
`Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\PycharmProjects\MyStuff\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'`

Comment: `on_message` is called with only one argument, `message`. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error its just that its not working. This is what pycharm says.

`Unresolved Renference ctx`
and
`Class 'Message' does not define '__await__', so the 'await' operator cannot be used on its instances`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Sorry had to Notify you.

Comment: Pycharm is noticing that `send_message` returns a `Message`, and thinks that you're trying to await that message, instead of awaiting the coroutine to get a `Message`.  I would ignore it.  Try running the code, you should get a more informative error.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Actually that didn't fix it. Await works but now it doesn't work and none of my bot commands work.Also I still get no errors

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have an error I can give now. I changed the post to have it.

Comment: [You cannot use `bot.say` outside of commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47899343/6779307).  An event, like `on_message`, is not the same as a command.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The thing is that if I switch it to `send_message` the await function won't work and the event is broken. Also ctx is an unresolved reference

Comment: `say` uses `send_message` internally.  Try `await client.send_message(message.channel, "...")`.  I think whatever you're trying to do with `Object` is the actual problem. Also, remove `ctx` from your event entirely.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That didn't fix it since ctx isn't working now. I updated the source code. its in the pastebin

Comment: `on_message` doesn't have a `ctx`.  Instead of using `ctx.message`, just use the message you pass as an argument. That's the only information the event is triggered with.

Comment: That fixed about everything except that it's only running the first thing on the list through the if statement. Also it won't run any command now @PatrickHaugh

Comment: See: [Why does on_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49331096/6779307).

Comment: I have no idea, but my objective is to react when you put in a command that doesn't exist. Now I'm just trying to get the bot to say that command does not exist when the exception `CommandNotFound` is activated. @PatrickHaugh

Comment: See: [How to respond to wrong user command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52121740/6779307)