# How to use discord bot commands and event both?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I need to make a bot that listen for messages written in a server, and at the same time accept commands.

```
# Create the Discord client
client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')


@client.event                                               #ricerca messaggi 
async def on_message(message):
    # Ignore messages made by the bot
    if(message.author == client.user):
        return
    a = ''
    a += message.embeds[0]["description"]
    if a == 'abcdef':
        print(' aaaaa ')



@client.command()
async def hello():
    await client.say('hello')


client.run('token')
```

How can I make it works?
I think the problem is that the bot continue cycling in the first event...
I read about sub_process but I do not understand how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Comment: the bot works, but It doesn't recognize the command

Comment: Also relevant: [You cannot use `bot.say` outside of a command.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897008/how-would-i-make-my-python-discord-bot-mimic-all-messages-sent/47899343#47899343)

Comment: yeah I'm wrong... Perviously I used a send embed... Anyway, how can I use both command and event? Can you make me an example with my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to add process_commands() at the end of your on_message. [This is because overriding the default on_message forbids commands from running](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).

```
@client.event                                               #ricerca messaggi 
async def on_message(message):
    # Ignore messages made by the bot
    if(message.author == client.user):
        return
    a = ''
    a += message.embeds[0]["description"]
    if a == 'abcdef':
        await message.channel.send(' aaaaa ')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: I tried but It doesn't works.. maybe I wrong with code... could you please write it all with my example?

Comment: I added the example, but i'm not entirely sure what you want to do with the embeds in a message.

Answer (score -1):

instead of `@client.event()` just do `@client.listen()` and it should work and remove `client = discord.Client()`

Comment: Your answer should be in detail as it doesn't have proper reason why it should be like this.