# How do I make my discord bot understand my word list? And execute it?

Tags: python, json, discord, nltk, message

So I have a discord bot right. Now normally the code that you would use fore the bot to reply to a user is this:

```
@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')
```

But I have a word list containing patterns(The possible words that a user could send) and responses(Responses to those specific keywords when said by the user), and what I want to do is connect this json file and make the bot understand the libraries that I already have and execute them. For example

```
{"intents":  [
 {"tags": "greetings",
  "patterns": ["hello", "hi", "good afternoon", "good evening", "good morning", "whats up", "how do you do", "hey", "yo","sup"],
  "responses": ["Hello!", "hey!", "what can I do for you?", "hey dude/miss!", "hey what up!", "Hio", "UwU", "hi"]

@client.command()
async def Sup (ctx):
    await ctx.send("Sup homie!")
```

but if a user reply's "sup" with lower case it won't reply because it doesn't have the lemmatizer module. So can anyone show me the proper code to use with all that in mind? Any help would be great! Thank you! :)

Comment: you don't have to use `client.command`. In documentation you should see function which gets every text from user and then you can use your list

Comment: Can you give an example? So that I can work off of that?

Comment: in [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference) you can see example which uses event `on_message` to get every message from use and it use `message.content.startswith('$hello')` to recognize command `hello`. And here you can use your list, lematization, NLTK, etc. Simply `client.command` is higher level - to make code simpler - but using `events` you work on lower level and you may have better control.

Comment: hmm ok sounds good I'll do some digging with that I appreciate the help!

Comment: I found even question [How to use discord bot commands and event both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705633/how-to-use-discord-bot-commands-and-event-both)

Comment: No he's talking about bot commands for the discord bot im talking about how to use a world-list that the bot can understand and execute. But I appreciate the recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

`bot.commands` is extension (you import it from `discord.ext`) which helps to make code simpler - ie. it automatically recognize if message has prefix, it splits message to words, and it assigns command to function.

But you don't have to use it. You can use event `on_message` to get full text from user and then you can process it on you own. It means you can compare with pattern/regex, lemmatize, use with NLTK, etc. But it also means you have to on your own recognize prefix (if you want to run code only when command has prefix), split message to words.

```
import discord
import random
import shlex  # to split `say "A B C"` as two elements `say` `"A B C"`

data = {
    'hello': ['Hello World!', 'Good Morning Vietnam!', 'Good Day My Lord']
}

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ignore messages made by the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # preprocessing message
    text = message.content.lower()
    #words = text.split(' ')        # 'say "A B C"' -> ['say', '"A', 'B', 'C"']
    words = list(shlex.shlex(text)) # 'say "A B C"' -> ['say', '"A B C"'] 
    if not words:
        await message.channel.send("I don't understand you: " + str(words))
        return

    first_word = words[0] 

    # only message which starts with prefix `$`
    #if not text.startswith('$'):
    #    return 

    found = False

    # compare message with dictionary
    for word, answers in data.items():
        #if text.startswith(word): # will treat `hellowin` like `hello`
        if first_word == word:     # will skip `hellowin` 
            found = True
            selected = random.choice(answers) 
            await message.channel.send(selected)

    if not found:
        await message.channel.send("I don't understand you: " + str(words))
    
client.run("MY_TOKEN")
```

---

**BTW:** you have example even in documentation in [Quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: I added some modifications to example

Comment: Oh ok but I'm getting this error do you know how to fix it? first_word = words[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: use `print(text, words)` to see what you get in message. If you have empty string then `words[0]` may not exists and you have to use `if len(words) > 0: ...` o shorter `if words:` to skip all code.

Comment: I added `if not words: return` to exit function when there is no words.